# Incrementally building a barplot in R

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to make a plot that shows the calorie count for different types of sandwich by sandwich shop. I.e. how much calories has a veggie sandwich at Subway vs Jimmy John's etc.

I would like to visualize this as a barplot, that

- has a bar for each sandwich's **calorie count**
- visibly **groups sandwiches by type**: *veggie*, *roast beef*, etc. where each group is split up according to the different vendors.

My data looks like this (EDITED for reproducability):

```
cleaninput <- data.frame ("type" = c("italian", "turkey", "roastbeef", "club", "veggie", "italian", "turkey", "roastbeef", "veggie"), 
"vendor" = c( "subway",  "subway",  "subway",  "subway",  "subway",  "jimmyjohns", "jimmyjohns", "jimmyjohns", "jimmyjohns"),
"calories" = c(410,280,320,310,230,640,510,540,690))
```

I try to iterate over the data like so, where `cleaninput` is my `data.frame`:

```
#set up barplot
barplot(height = mean(cleaninput[['calories']]))
#iterate over sandwich types
for (t in levels(cleaninput[['type']]))
{
  cat(t,"\n")

  barplot(cleaninput[cleaninput[['type']]==t,][['calories']], add = TRUE)
}
```

The idea being to first set up the barplot, then add the bars for each sandwich type iteratively. I [understood](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/2-barplots-in-the-same-graph-td794388.html) the `add` setting to do this. I have done similar things with regular plots, using the `lines` and `points` commands and reproducing an example below -- this is what I want to transfer into a barplot.

[image]

However, it does not work, as it seems to mush all the bars on top of each other (cf output below).

My questions

- (how) can I fix this? Preferably I would like to use base R rather than ggplot to make this more portable.
- is there a better approach than a `for`-loop?

I looked at [tutorials](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html) for grouped barplots but did not see how they translated to my problem.

Current output:

[image: ugly R plot]

Comment: Please provide your data or a subset of it in a usable form -- one we can copy and paste without having to do formatting e.g. by pasting the output of  `dput(cleaninput)`.  You might consider learning ggplot2 instead. http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization

Comment: @R.S. Thanks, I thought my example was copy&pasteable but it is not and I have replaced it with a correct one. Thanks for the suggestions of ggplot, but as I said above I'd like to get this to work in base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution in base plot as requested, since that is your preference over ggpltot2.

First step is to get your data in wide format used in base plot for barplots, e.g. by using `reshape2::dcast` or `tidyr::spread`

```
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
cleaninput_spread <- cleaninput %>% spread(type, calories) %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames(var="vendor")
cleaninput_spread

>            club italian roastbeef turkey veggie
> jimmyjohns   NA     640       540    510    690
> subway      310     410       320    280    230
```

Replace NA values with 0:

```
cleaninput_spread[is.na(cleaninput_spread)] <- 0
```

Stacked barplot in base:

```
barplot(as.matrix(cleaninput_spread), main="Calories per Sandwich, by shop",
        xlab="Sandwich", ylab="Calories",
        col=c("darkblue","red"),
        legend = rownames(cleaninput_spread))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sir, that is very helpful! I have a quick followup if you don't mind: I see this `%>%` operator from time to time & understand it is a pipe-like command; do I read the code correctly that I could also perform all these operations in individual commands and `%>%` is mainly for convenience & readability? Thanks again for the plot!

Comment: Yes, this is equivalent to `column_to_rownames(remove_rownames(spread(cleaninput, type, calories)), var="vendor")` and can assign each nested function to separate variables if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
type<-c("italian","turkey","roastbeef","club","veggie","italian","turkey","roastbeef","veggie")
vendor<-c(rep("subway",5),rep("jimmyjohns",4))
calories<-c(410,280,320,310,230,640,510,540,690)
size<-c(rep(6,5),rep(8,4))

cleaninput<-data.frame(type,vendor,calories,size)

#first you calculate the mean by type using by function (base package)  

calor.by.type<-by(cleaninput$calories,INDICES = list(cleaninput$type),FUN = mean)

#then you plot the result from by function

barplot(calor.by.type,main="by function")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, it is not really what I'm trying to do -- I'd like to split up each type by vendor, i.e. Subway's "club" versus jimmyjohns "Club", etc. I have added an expected output example to my question and tried to clarify the wording... sorry if I wasnt quite clear.